# Viewgroup not Drawing its Children

Tags: android, view, viewgroup, ui-thread

I have an activity that gets a bitmap from the sdcard. Its view is set to a custom viewgroup. i have dynamically added a view containing the bitmap to the viewgroup and used a handler to update the viewgroup in the UI thread, but to no avail. The viewgroup doesn't show the bitmap. The viewgroup code I have not written myself but ought to allow the user to swipe the screen to load different views/bitmaps.

i have checked to see if the bitmap is not null and placed log statements in various places in both files. Any ideas as to why the viewgroup's children are not being drawn?

The activity

```
public class HorizontalPagerActivity extends Activity {


    private static final String TAG = "*********hpActivity";
    private Context mContext = this;
    File tempFile;
    byte [] imageArray;
    private Bitmap b = null;
    private Handler handler;

     @Override 
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);



            setContentView(R.layout.hpview);
            final ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.hpview); 
            handler = new Handler();



            tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
                    getAbsolutePath() + "/"+"image.jpeg");

            Log.e(TAG, "image length = "+tempFile.length());

            imageArray = new byte[(int)tempFile.length()];





         try{

                InputStream is = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);


                int i = 0;

                while (dis.available() > 0 ) {
                imageArray[i] = dis.readByte();
                i++;
                }

                dis.close();


           } catch (Exception e) {

                   e.printStackTrace();
                }



           Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageArray, 0, imageArray.length);
          // Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
           b = bm.copy(bm.getConfig(), true);

            if(b == null){
                Log.e(TAG, "b = null");
            }else{
                Log.e(TAG, "b =  not null");
            }


             Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);

             Log.e(TAG, "canvas created");

             final View view = new View(this);
             Log.e(TAG, "view created");

            // LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

           //  view.setLayoutParams(lp);
             view.draw(canvas);
             viewgroup.addView(view);

             Log.e(TAG, "view added to viewgroup");


             Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {



                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                Log.e(TAG, "about to inval viewgroup");
                                viewgroup.invalidate();
                                Log.e(TAG, "finished inval viewgroup"); 

                            }
                        });

                }
            };
            new Thread(runnable).start();

            Log.e(TAG, "finished handler"); 








             /*
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e(TAG, "about to inval viewgroup");
                    viewgroup.postInvalidate();
                    Log.e(TAG, "finished inval viewgroup");
                }
            });

             */

             Log.e(TAG, "no of chidren = "+viewgroup.getChildCount());





     }


}
```

The viewgroup

```
/**
 * A view group that allows users to switch between multiple screens (layouts) in the same way as
 * the Android home screen (Launcher application).
 * <p>
 * You can add and remove views using the normal methods {@link ViewGroup#addView(View)},
 * {@link ViewGroup#removeView(View)} etc. You may want to listen for updates by calling
 * {@link HorizontalPager#setOnScreenSwitchListener(OnScreenSwitchListener)} in order to perform
 * operations once a new screen has been selected.
 *
 * Modifications from original version (ysamlan): Animate argument in setCurrentScreen and duration
 * in snapToScreen; onInterceptTouchEvent handling to support nesting a vertical Scrollview inside
 * the RealViewSwitcher; allowing snapping to a view even during an ongoing scroll; snap to
 * next/prev view on 25% scroll change; density-independent swipe sensitivity; width-independent
 * pager animation durations on scrolling to properly handle large screens without excessively
 * long animations.
 *
 * Other modifications:
 * (aveyD) Handle orientation changes properly and fully snap to the right position.
 *
 * @author Marc Reichelt, <a href="http://www.marcreichelt.de/">http://www.marcreichelt.de/</a>
 * @version 0.1.0
 */
public final class HorizontalPager extends ViewGroup {
    /*
     * How long to animate between screens when programmatically setting with setCurrentScreen using
     * the animate parameter
     */
    private static final int ANIMATION_SCREEN_SET_DURATION_MILLIS = 500;
    // What fraction (1/x) of the screen the user must swipe to indicate a page change
    private static final int FRACTION_OF_SCREEN_WIDTH_FOR_SWIPE = 4;
    private static final int INVALID_SCREEN = -1;
    /*
     * Velocity of a swipe (in density-independent pixels per second) to force a swipe to the
     * next/previous screen. Adjusted into mDensityAdjustedSnapVelocity on init.
     */
    private static final int SNAP_VELOCITY_DIP_PER_SECOND = 600;
    // Argument to getVelocity for units to give pixels per second (1 = pixels per millisecond).
    private static final int VELOCITY_UNIT_PIXELS_PER_SECOND = 1000;

    private static final int TOUCH_STATE_REST = 0;
    private static final int TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING = 1;
    private static final int TOUCH_STATE_VERTICAL_SCROLLING = -1;
    private int mCurrentScreen;
    private int mDensityAdjustedSnapVelocity;
    private boolean mFirstLayout = true;
    private float mLastMotionX;
    private float mLastMotionY;
    private OnScreenSwitchListener mOnScreenSwitchListener;
    private int mMaximumVelocity;
    private int mNextScreen = INVALID_SCREEN;
    private Scroller mScroller;
    private int mTouchSlop;
    private int mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
    private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;
    private int mLastSeenLayoutWidth = -1;
    private static final String TAG = "*********horizontalpager";
    private Bitmap bm = null;

    /**
     * Simple constructor to use when creating a view from code.
     *
     * @param context The Context the view is running in, through which it can
     *        access the current theme, resources, etc.
     */
    public HorizontalPager(final Context context) {
        super(context);
        Log.e(TAG, "inside hp standard constructor");
        init();

    }

    /**
     * Constructor that is called when inflating a view from XML. This is called
     * when a view is being constructed from an XML file, supplying attributes
     * that were specified in the XML file. This version uses a default style of
     * 0, so the only attribute values applied are those in the Context's Theme
     * and the given AttributeSet.
     *
     * <p>
     * The method onFinishInflate() will be called after all children have been
     * added.
     *
     * @param context The Context the view is running in, through which it can
     *        access the current theme, resources, etc.
     * @param attrs The attributes of the XML tag that is inflating the view.
     * @see #View(Context, AttributeSet, int)
     */
    public HorizontalPager(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Log.e(TAG, "inside hp constructor for xml inflation");
        init();


    }

    /**
     * Sets up the scroller and touch/fling sensitivity parameters for the pager.
     */
    private void init() {
        mScroller = new Scroller(getContext());

        // Calculate the density-dependent snap velocity in pixels
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay()
                .getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        mDensityAdjustedSnapVelocity =
                (int) (displayMetrics.density * SNAP_VELOCITY_DIP_PER_SECOND);

        final ViewConfiguration configuration = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext());
        mTouchSlop = configuration.getScaledTouchSlop();
        mMaximumVelocity = configuration.getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        final int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        final int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        if (widthMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ViewSwitcher can only be used in EXACTLY mode.");
        }

        final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ViewSwitcher can only be used in EXACTLY mode.");
        }

        // The children are given the same width and height as the workspace
        final int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            getChildAt(i).measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }

        if (mFirstLayout) {
            scrollTo(mCurrentScreen * width, 0);
            mFirstLayout = false;
        }

        else if (width != mLastSeenLayoutWidth) { // Width has changed
            /*
             * Recalculate the width and scroll to the right position to be sure we're in the right
             * place in the event that we had a rotation that didn't result in an activity restart
             * (code by aveyD). Without this you can end up between two pages after a rotation.
             */
            Display display =
                    ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                            .getDefaultDisplay();
            int displayWidth = display.getWidth();

            mNextScreen = Math.max(0, Math.min(getCurrentScreen(), getChildCount() - 1));
            final int newX = mNextScreen * displayWidth;
            final int delta = newX - getScrollX();

            mScroller.startScroll(getScrollX(), 0, delta, 0, 0);
        }

        mLastSeenLayoutWidth   = width;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(final boolean changed, final int l, final int t, final int r,
            final int b) {
        int childLeft = 0;
        final int count = getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
                final int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
                child.layout(childLeft, 0, childLeft + childWidth, child.getMeasuredHeight());
                childLeft += childWidth;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
        /*
         * By Yoni Samlan: Modified onInterceptTouchEvent based on standard ScrollView's
         * onIntercept. The logic is designed to support a nested vertically scrolling view inside
         * this one; once a scroll registers for X-wise scrolling, handle it in this view and don't
         * let the children, but once a scroll registers for y-wise scrolling, let the children
         * handle it exclusively.
         */
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        boolean intercept = false;

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                /*
                 * If we're in a horizontal scroll event, take it (intercept further events). But if
                 * we're mid-vertical-scroll, don't even try; let the children deal with it. If we
                 * haven't found a scroll event yet, check for one.
                 */
                if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING) {
                    /*
                     * We've already started a horizontal scroll; set intercept to true so we can
                     * take the remainder of all touch events in onTouchEvent.
                     */
                    intercept = true;
                } else if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_VERTICAL_SCROLLING) {
                    // Let children handle the events for the duration of the scroll event.
                    intercept = false;
                } else { // We haven't picked up a scroll event yet; check for one.

                    /*
                     * If we detected a horizontal scroll event, start stealing touch events (mark
                     * as scrolling). Otherwise, see if we had a vertical scroll event -- if so, let
                     * the children handle it and don't look to intercept again until the motion is
                     * done.
                     */

                    final float x = ev.getX();
                    final int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(x - mLastMotionX);
                    boolean xMoved = xDiff > mTouchSlop;

                    if (xMoved) {
                        // Scroll if the user moved far enough along the X axis
                        mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING;
                        mLastMotionX = x;
                    }

                    final float y = ev.getY();
                    final int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(y - mLastMotionY);
                    boolean yMoved = yDiff > mTouchSlop;

                    if (yMoved) {
                        mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_VERTICAL_SCROLLING;
                    }
                }

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Release the drag.
                mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                /*
                 * No motion yet, but register the coordinates so we can check for intercept at the
                 * next MOVE event.
                 */
                mLastMotionY = ev.getY();
                mLastMotionX = ev.getX();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        return intercept;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
         Log.e(TAG, "inside hp ontouchEvent");

        if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
            mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
        }
        mVelocityTracker.addMovement(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        final float x = ev.getX();

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                /*
                 * If being flinged and user touches, stop the fling. isFinished will be false if
                 * being flinged.
                 */
                if (!mScroller.isFinished()) {
                    mScroller.abortAnimation();
                }

                // Remember where the motion event started
                mLastMotionX = x;

                if (mScroller.isFinished()) {
                    mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
                } else {
                    mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING;
                }

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                final int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(x - mLastMotionX);
                boolean xMoved = xDiff > mTouchSlop;

                if (xMoved) {
                    // Scroll if the user moved far enough along the X axis
                    mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING;
                }

                if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING) {
                    // Scroll to follow the motion event
                    final int deltaX = (int) (mLastMotionX - x);
                    mLastMotionX = x;
                    final int scrollX = getScrollX();

                    if (deltaX < 0) {
                        if (scrollX > 0) {
                            scrollBy(Math.max(-scrollX, deltaX), 0);
                        }
                    } else if (deltaX > 0) {
                        final int availableToScroll =
                                getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1).getRight() - scrollX - getWidth();

                        if (availableToScroll > 0) {
                            scrollBy(Math.min(availableToScroll, deltaX), 0);
                        }
                    }
                }

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING) {
                    final VelocityTracker velocityTracker = mVelocityTracker;
                    velocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(VELOCITY_UNIT_PIXELS_PER_SECOND,
                            mMaximumVelocity);
                    int velocityX = (int) velocityTracker.getXVelocity();

                    if (velocityX > mDensityAdjustedSnapVelocity && mCurrentScreen > 0) {
                        // Fling hard enough to move left
                        snapToScreen(mCurrentScreen - 1);
                    } else if (velocityX < -mDensityAdjustedSnapVelocity
                            && mCurrentScreen < getChildCount() - 1) {
                        // Fling hard enough to move right
                        snapToScreen(mCurrentScreen + 1);
                    } else {
                        snapToDestination();
                    }

                    if (mVelocityTracker != null) {
                        mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                        mVelocityTracker = null;
                    }
                }

                mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void computeScroll() {
        if (mScroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
            scrollTo(mScroller.getCurrX(), mScroller.getCurrY());
            postInvalidate();
        } else if (mNextScreen != INVALID_SCREEN) {
            mCurrentScreen = Math.max(0, Math.min(mNextScreen, getChildCount() - 1));

            // Notify observer about screen change
            if (mOnScreenSwitchListener != null) {
                mOnScreenSwitchListener.onScreenSwitched(mCurrentScreen);
            }

            mNextScreen = INVALID_SCREEN;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the index of the currently displayed screen.
     *
     * @return The index of the currently displayed screen.
     */
    public int getCurrentScreen() {
        return mCurrentScreen;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the current screen.
     *
     * @param currentScreen The new screen.
     * @param animate True to smoothly scroll to the screen, false to snap instantly
     */
    public void setCurrentScreen(final int currentScreen, final boolean animate) {
        mCurrentScreen = Math.max(0, Math.min(currentScreen, getChildCount() - 1));
        if (animate) {
            snapToScreen(currentScreen, ANIMATION_SCREEN_SET_DURATION_MILLIS);
        } else {
            scrollTo(mCurrentScreen * getWidth(), 0);
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the {@link OnScreenSwitchListener}.
     *
     * @param onScreenSwitchListener The listener for switch events.
     */
    public void setOnScreenSwitchListener(final OnScreenSwitchListener onScreenSwitchListener) {
        mOnScreenSwitchListener = onScreenSwitchListener;
    }

    /**
     * Snaps to the screen we think the user wants (the current screen for very small movements; the
     * next/prev screen for bigger movements).
     */
    private void snapToDestination() {
        final int screenWidth = getWidth();
        int scrollX = getScrollX();
        int whichScreen = mCurrentScreen;
        int deltaX = scrollX - (screenWidth * mCurrentScreen);

        // Check if they want to go to the prev. screen
        if ((deltaX < 0) && mCurrentScreen != 0
                && ((screenWidth / FRACTION_OF_SCREEN_WIDTH_FOR_SWIPE) < -deltaX)) {
            whichScreen--;
            // Check if they want to go to the next screen
        } else if ((deltaX > 0) && (mCurrentScreen + 1 != getChildCount())
                && ((screenWidth / FRACTION_OF_SCREEN_WIDTH_FOR_SWIPE) < deltaX)) {
            whichScreen++;
        }

        snapToScreen(whichScreen);
    }

    /**
     * Snap to a specific screen, animating automatically for a duration proportional to the
     * distance left to scroll.
     *
     * @param whichScreen Screen to snap to
     */
    private void snapToScreen(final int whichScreen) {
        snapToScreen(whichScreen, -1);
    }

    /**
     * Snaps to a specific screen, animating for a specific amount of time to get there.
     *
     * @param whichScreen Screen to snap to
     * @param duration -1 to automatically time it based on scroll distance; a positive number to
     *            make the scroll take an exact duration.
     */
    private void snapToScreen(final int whichScreen, final int duration) {
        /*
         * Modified by Yoni Samlan: Allow new snapping even during an ongoing scroll animation. This
         * is intended to make HorizontalPager work as expected when used in conjunction with a
         * RadioGroup used as "tabbed" controls. Also, make the animation take a percentage of our
         * normal animation time, depending how far they've already scrolled.
         */
        mNextScreen = Math.max(0, Math.min(whichScreen, getChildCount() - 1));
        final int newX = mNextScreen * getWidth();
        final int delta = newX - getScrollX();

        if (duration < 0) {
             // E.g. if they've scrolled 80% of the way, only animation for 20% of the duration
            mScroller.startScroll(getScrollX(), 0, delta, 0, (int) (Math.abs(delta)
                    / (float) getWidth() * ANIMATION_SCREEN_SET_DURATION_MILLIS));
        } else {
            mScroller.startScroll(getScrollX(), 0, delta, 0, duration);
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "about to call inval****************** on viewgroup");
        invalidate();

    }

    /**
     * Listener for the event that the HorizontalPager switches to a new view.
     */
    public static interface OnScreenSwitchListener {
        /**
         * Notifies listeners about the new screen. Runs after the animation completed.
         *
         * @param screen The new screen index.
         */
        void onScreenSwitched(int screen);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Log.e(TAG, "inside hp ondraw()");

    }
```

output:

```
01-13 14:52:00.290: ERROR/*********horizontalpager(9206): inside hp constructor for xml inflation
01-13 14:52:00.295: ERROR/*********hpActivity(9206): image length = 13215
01-13 14:52:00.295: INFO/global(9206): Default buffer size used in BufferedInputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required.
01-13 14:52:00.730: DEBUG/dalvikvm(9206): GC freed 353 objects / 40040 bytes in 58ms
01-13 14:52:00.740: ERROR/*********hpActivity(9206): b =  not null
01-13 14:52:00.740: ERROR/*********hpActivity(9206): canvas created
01-13 14:52:00.740: ERROR/*********hpActivity(9206): view created
01-13 14:52:00.740: ERROR/*********hpActivity(9206): view added to viewgroup
01-13 14:52:00.740: ERROR/*********hpActivity(9206): finished handler
01-13 14:52:00.740: ERROR/*********hpActivity(9206): no of chidren = 1
01-13 14:52:00.775: ERROR/*********hpActivity(9206): about to inval viewgroup
01-13 14:52:00.775: ERROR/*********hpActivity(9206): finished inval viewgroup
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Lose the Canvas, unless you intend to draw into the image you do not need it.
2. Your image loading code is horrific. Use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(..)` instead.
3. The `Bitmap` object you get from `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(..)` should go inside an `ImageView`, **not** a `View`.

   ```
   File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image.jpeg");
   if (file.exists() && file.canRead()) {
       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.toString());
       if (bitmap != null) {
           ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
           view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
           viewgroup.addView(view);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks alot! i just used an imageview to place the bitmap in and it works with my original code. I can see what you mean by horrific code now. i'll change that now. thanks again